# Marginal and joint asymptotic normality

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

Suppose we have an i.i.d. data set $\{X_{i}:i=1,...,n\}$ where each $X_{i}$ is a real random variable. Let $X=(X_{1},...,X_{n})$. There are $J$ real-valued functions $g_{1},...,g_{J}$ such that for each $j=1,...,J$, $(g_{j}(X)-\theta_{j})$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ for some constants $\theta_{1},...,\theta_{J}$. Now in order to have joint asymptotic normality, i.e., the vector $(g_{1}(X)-\theta_{1},...,g_{J}(X)-\theta_{J})$ converges to a multivariate normal distribution, is it sufficient to show that covariance $cov(g_{k}(X),g_{j}(X))$ converges to some constant for every $k\neq j$?

Comment: No. You can have normal marginals that are not jointly normal; see, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d . Covariances are not enough. You would have to argue that $\lambda\cdot (g_1(X)-\theta_1, \dots, g_J(X)-\theta_J)$ converges to normal for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^J$, which requires substantially more than an argument about the covariances.

Comment: @Galton Many thanks! That explains.